# Google Maps Infowindow not appearing, custom or default

Tags: objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using the most recent version of Google Maps SDK via their official CocoaPod.

I should point out that everything used to work until I updated the CocoaPod. Here is some of the code for creating my markers:

```
    UIImage *markerIcon = [self imageFromView:view];
            marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.50f, 0.90);
            marker.icon = markerIcon;
            marker.map = mapView;
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([entry.latitude doubleValue], [entry.longitude doubleValue]);
            marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.44f, 0.45f);
            marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
```

My map delegate methods are being called because I can see my log statements:

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    NSLog(@"Custom info window!");
    CustomInfoWindow *view =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomInfoWindow" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    view.layer.zPosition = 99;

    MapMarkerData *markerData = [MapMarkerData new];
    markerData = marker.userData;

    view.storeName.text = markerData.title;
    view.storeAddress.text = markerData.address;
    view.storeRacks.text = markerData.racks;

    return view;
}
```

I have tried setting the layers zPositionto MAXFLOAT with no luck.

Returning `nil` from `markerInfoWindow` should display the default info window which doesn't work either.

I have tried this on iOS 8.1, 9.2.1 and 9.3.1 all with the same results, any pointers here?

**EDIT:** I downgraded the Google Maps CocoaPod to version 1.12.3 (from 1.13.0) and it works as expected now, can anyone point out why? I don't see anything different in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I also have issues but I've fix the display issue. 
You need to use `markerInfoContent` instead of `markerInfoWindow`.

But, I have display issues with the new sdk, I'll stay on the 1.12.3 version ;)